# Does $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ form a metric space with this distance/similarity measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the set $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$, where two functions $f$ and $g$ are said to be equal, if they agree almost everywhere. I would like to define a distance/similarity measure and would like to study its properties such as whether it would along with this set, forms a metric space.

Let $f$,$g$ be two functions on this set. We define a normalized cross correlation function as 
$$h(x) = \frac{\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t+x)\mathrm dt}{\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)^2\mathrm dt \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)^2\mathrm dt}$$

and our distance measure is given as $$d(f,g) = \frac{1}{\sup_x |h(x)|} - 1.$$

What I am interested to know is whether this set along with this distance measure qualifies as a metric space and also whether it has any interesting properties.

**Modification** (as it doesnt sound interesting in this current form) I hope its ok in this special case.

First we define an equivalence class and then modify the metric (infact would like to call it a similarity rather than metric and disacuss its properties and ask whether it would be modified to a metric if necessary)

**Equivalence class :**

Let $f$ be a function and we define its equivalence class as $\{kf_{\theta}\}$, $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{$\theta \in [0,\pi]}$, $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi], k \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $$f_{\theta} = f \cos(\theta) + f_h \sin(\theta)$$ where $f_h$ is the hilbert transform of $f$.

**Similarity measure (metric)**

let $$h(x) = \frac{\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t+x)\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)^2\mathrm dt \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)^2\mathrm dt}}.$$

Now define $$H(x) = \sqrt{h(x)^2 + h_h(x)^2}$$ where $h_h(x)$ is the hilbert transform of $h(x)$.

and our similarity measure is given as $$ s(f,g) = \sup_x H(x). $$

Define metric as $$d(f,g) =-\log(s(f,g)).$$

Is $d(f,g)$ a metric in the usual sense? Does this form a metric space?

PS : We assume sufficient regularity requirements on this space for the Hilbert transform to exist.

Comment: I think you may need more restrictions than just $L^2$: How would you define distance from, say $f = 0$?

Comment: @T.Bongers : Looks like we have to exclude $f=0$ from this set.

Comment: Do you want the square root in the denominator? Otherwise, $d(f,f)\ne0$.

Comment: If you do include the square root in the denominator, we get $d(f,-f)=0$.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for reminding the square root for denominator. I want to include square root.

Comment: @Rob to avoid d(f,-f) != 0, I need $f,g$ are not orthogonal to each other. (in the dot product norm).

Comment: $f$ and $-f$ are not orthogonal to each other. If $d$ were a metric, $d(f,g)=0\implies f=g$. $d$ does not seem to be a metric.

Comment: @robjohn : Did you see this after the latest edits.

Comment: @RajeshD: Are you sure that $\{f_\theta\}$ is an equivalence class? I don't believe that $f$ is in the "equivalence class" of $f_{\pi/4}$. Consider the fourier transforms of each.

Comment: @robjohn : What I mean is all the functions of the form $f \cos(\theta) + f_h \sin(\theta)$ for different values of $\theta$ in $[0,\pi]$, including $f$ ($\theta = 0$) are to be considered one and the same, meaning they are equivalent. So $f$ and $f_{\pi/4}$ are one and the same, so $s(f,f_{\pi/4}) = 1$, meaning they are equivalent, $1$ is the maximum value of similarity.

Comment: @robjohn : Consider all $f$ to be zero mean! meaning zero zero frquency coeff in Fourier transform.

Comment: @robjohn : $f = f_{\pi/4}\cos(-\pi/4) + f_{h_{\pi/4}}\sin(-\pi/4)$. So I think $\theta$ should be in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Let me know What you think.

Comment: @robjohn : I have edited to make $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: @RajeshD: I forgot that $H^2f=-f$ (I was thinking $H^2f=f$). So yes, this does form an equivalence class.

Comment: @Robjohn : After seeing your comment, my first fear was $H^2 f = f$ being true, quickly verified Wikipedia, but after calculations made [-pi,pi]. Your comment made me verify things.

Comment: @RajeshD: The kernel for the Hilbert Transform is odd, so the multiplier is going to be pure imaginary ($i$ for $\xi\gt0$ and $-i$ for $\xi\lt0$). Thus, the square of the Hilbert multiplier is $-1$, not $1$.

Comment: How about $d(f,2f)$? Should it be zero? If you are going to normalise in your definition of $h$ you really should just work with functions with unit $L^2$ norm instead. This simplifies your notation and gets rid of the conformal degree of freedom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many, many things wrong with your question. The below may not completely answer/fix them (since I am not sure about your motivations), but should at least get you started on the right track.

The starting point for you seems to be the correlation

$$ \int f(t) g(t+x) \mathrm{d}t  $$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have

$$ \left| \int f(t) g(t+x) \mathrm{d}t\right| \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 \tag{*}$$

where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the $L^2$ norm. The Cauchy-Schwarz (and in general, Hölder's) inequality is known to be sharp (see, for example, Hardy-Littlewood-Polya); that is to say that equality in (*) is attained if and only if $$f(t) = C g(t+x)\tag{**}$$ where $C$ is any scalar.

This means that for your modified $h(x)$, you have that $|h(x)| = 1$ if and only if there is some constant $C$ such that $f$ and $g$ are related by (**), and in general $|h(x)| \leq 1$.

This also means that if you want to define some sort of metric of the form 
$$ d(f,g) = F(\sup_{x} h ) $$
where $F(1) = 0$, you need to quotient out by all symmetries which makes $d(f,g) = 0$ when $f \neq g$.

---

With these all said, this means that the only reasonable space on which any semblance of $d(f,g)$ can satisfy the requirement that $d(f,g) = 0 \iff f = g$ would be if you take the underlying space to be

$$ L^2 / \sim $$

where the equivalence relation is that $f \sim g$ if (**) holds for some constants $C$ and $x$. If you do this you will find the zero function somewhat lonely and isolated, so it is perhaps best to start with $L^2 \setminus \{0\}$ instead.

In other words, you should be looking at the projective space associated to the vector space $L^2$, with the additional identification that translations of functions are identified. Now, projective Hilbert spaces are quite well studied in the context of quantum mechanics (see, for example, [this MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84183/projective-hilbert-space-l2)), but we needn't go in that direction.

---

So I propose the following modification of your definitions.

**Underlying set**: Let $M$ be the set of $(L^2(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C}) \setminus\{0\} )/ \sim$ such that $f\sim g$ iff there exists $(C,x)$ such that (**) holds.

**Similarity measure**: Let

$$ h(f,g) = \sup_{x} \frac{\left|\int \overline{f}(t) g(t+x) \mathrm{d}x\right|}{\|f\|_2\|g\|_2} $$

One easily checks that this is independent of the representative in the equivalence class $[f]\in M$. By the sharpness of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have that $h(f,g) = 1 \iff [f] = [g]$. Otherwise $h(f,g) \in [0,1)$. (Note that $h(f,g) = 0$ is possible: choose $f,g$ such that their Fourier transforms $\hat{f},\hat{g} \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C})$ with disjoint support. Spatial translations and absolute scaling do not change the frequency support, so by Parseval $h(f,g) = 0$. This in particular means that neither of the definitions for $d$ in your original post are good, since you run into problems with $\frac{1}{0}$ or $\log 0$ not being real numbers.)

Now clearly $h(f,g)$ is symmetric. So in order to get a "metric" on the space $M$, it suffices to find a function $F: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $F(1) = 0$
2. $F|_{[0,1)} > 0$
3. For $d(f,g) = F\circ h(f,g)$, the triangle inequality is satisfied.

Since we are essentially working with the unit sphere in a Hilbert space, inspired by the Law of Cosine a reasonable choice seems to be $F = \arccos$ with the usual branch. This trivially satisfies the first two requirements.

The third requirement we check using the sum of angle formulae for $\cos$ which implies

$$ \arccos A + \arccos B = \arccos (A B - \sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}) \tag{***}$$

Where given our choice of $A,B\in [0,1]$ we have that $AB\in [0,1]$ and $\sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}\in [0,1]$, we have that the argument $(A B - \sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}) \in [-1,1]$, and thus (***) holds for the branch of $\arccos$ such that its image of $[-1,1]$ is $[0,\pi]$ and is strictly decreasing.

Now, let $A = h(f_1,g)$ and $B = h(f_2,g)$. Since $h$ is independent of representative, assume $f_1,f_2,g$ all have unit $L^2$ norm.

Then we note that 
$$ \langle f_1,f_2\rangle = \langle f_1,g\rangle\langle f_2,g\rangle + \langle f_1 - \langle f_1,g\rangle g, f_2 - \langle f_2,g\rangle g\rangle $$
so by Cauchy-Schwarz on the last term
$$ \langle f_1,f_2 \rangle \geq \langle f_1,g\rangle\langle f_2,g\rangle - \sqrt{ (1 - \langle f_1,g\rangle^2)(1 - \langle f_2,g\rangle^2)} $$
Taking the sup over translations this implies
$$ h(f_1,f_2) \geq A B - \sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)} \tag{****}$$

Combining this with the formula (***) and using the monotonicity of $\arccos$, we obtain 
$$ \arccos h(f_1,g) + \arccos h(f_2,g) \geq \arccos h(f_1,f_2) $$
which is precisely the triangle inequality
$$ d(f_1,f_2) \leq d(f_1,g) + d(f_2,g) $$

Comment: I fully agree with your suggestion to consider $$ L^2 / \sim $$, that the translations be identified.  In the second part of your answer, you raise the question of $d(f,g) =  \infty$, that is similarity being zero and then taking a logarithm of it introduces infinity. The example you have given is choose f,g such that their Fourier transforms f^,g^∈C∞0(R;C) with disjoint support. Does it violate with "PS : We assume sufficient regularity requirements on this space for the Hilbert transform to exist."...,

Comment: If it does not violate, then I'd like like to impose differentiability or such regularity requirements and make $d(f,g) = \infty $ to become impossible. I'd like to mention that the equivalence class I have defined in my question (fcos(theta) + fhsin(theta), is very important and i'd like to proceed in that direction. I don't want to go with simply correlation.

Comment: @RajeshD: The Hilbert transform is a Fourier multiplier. Thus if $f,g$ have disjoint Fourier support, both the $h$ and $h_h$ in your "modified" version will return 0. One can even choose $f,g$ to be Schwartz class. So neither regularity nor Hilbert transform will save you from the problem of $d(f,g) = \infty$.

Comment: Hi Willie : Is the negative square of your metric $-d(f,g)^2$ a conditionally positive defnite kernel? Its important for me to know as if it turns out, I can have an isometric embedding of this metric space into a Hilbert space.

Comment: No idea (in fact I am not familiar with your terminology "conditionally positive definite kernel", especially in this context).

Comment: $g : R\times R \to \mathbb{R}$ is the kernel in question. (R being the metric space) and $g$ is given as $g(x,y) = -d(x,y)^2$. Kernel $g$ is positive definite iff $ \sum_{1 \le i,j \le n} c_i c_j g(x_i,x_j) > 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall c_i,c_j \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x_i \in R $ and conditional, if it needs to hold only when $\sum_{1\le i\le n} c_i = 0$.

Comment: Schoenberg theorem. called as Hilbertian metric, needed for isometric embedding into a Hilbert space.

Comment: I want use instead of $\theta$(theta = arccos(s(f,g)), I can still use $d(f,g) = \sqrt{2(1-\cos(\theta)))}$, this is a valid metric also known as angular distance (actually same as L2 norm with magnitudes equated to one, or distance after projected onto the unit sphere) if i am right, and what I came to know from some references it is an Hilbertian metric. Let me know if I am right with this metric.

Answer (score 0):

Willie, you just gave me everything I could dream, that too in mathematically brilliant way! (subject to the validity of what follows). All I have to do is replace $\log$ with $\arccos$ in my modified question and ofcourse identify translations. I'll try and explain briefly below by summarizing everything.

Consider $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \setminus \{0\}$ and impose the following equivalence class on this.

**Equivalence class $@$**

Let $f$ be a function and we define its equivalence class as $@ = \{kf_{\theta}(x+\tau)\}$, $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi], k \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$,$\tau \in \mathbb{R}$ and $$f_{\theta}(x) = f(x) \cos(\theta) + f_h(x) \sin(\theta)$$ where $f_h(x)$ is the hilbert transform of $f(x)$.

Lets us denote this set together with this equivalence class as $R = (L^2(\mathbb{R}) \setminus \{0\})/@$.

(All I did is apart from what is in the question, I have identified translations).

Now we define metric just as in the question except replacing $\log$ with $\arccos$. Just to summarize...

Given $f,g \in R$, let $$h(x) = \frac{\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t+x)\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)^2\mathrm dt \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)^2\mathrm dt}}.$$

Now define $$H(x) = \sqrt{h(x)^2 + h_h(x)^2}$$ where $h_h(x)$ is the hilbert transform of $h(x)$.

and our similarity measure is given as $$ s(f,g) = \sup_x H(x). $$

Define metric as $$d(f,g) = \arccos(s(f,g)).$$

**Willie with his proposition of his metric on his set $M$, has just proved that the above  defined set $R$ with metric $d(f,g)$ is indeed a metric space.**

How? We just have to move from $R$ to $M$ (Willie's space, see his answer for definition) (Hilbert space with translations identified and zero element removed) by replacing object $f$ by $F(x) = f(x) + if_h(x)$. Thats it!

If we denote Willie's cosine metric on $M$ as $w$, then given any $f,g \in R$, we create  objects $F,G \in M$ given as $F(x) = f(x) + if_h(x), G(x) = g(x) + ig_h(x)$.

Now it can be seen that 
$$d(f,g) = w(F,G)$$ Hence $(R,d)$ is a metric space.

Please correct me wherever I am wrong!

**PS : If I had the power, I'd would like give Willie's answer a thousand upvotes! (as gratitude) .**

PS : I have been using $\log$ in all my experiments, but now I replace it with $\arccos$ (I'd like to call this Willie's cosine metric). If the results are physically useful and If by chance I get to publish it, I'd like to quote this Q&A and give credit to Willie, robjohn and all others who have commented on this.

Comment: @Willie ; I definitely expect lot of mistakes in my post, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/528051/2987