# Does negative distributive property of convolution over cross correlation holds?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution

Let $\star$ denote [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) binary operation and $\otimes$ denote [cross correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) binary operation between two functions.

Let $f,g,h$ be functions. Does this negative distribution property holds? $$f\star ( g\otimes h) = - (f \star g) \otimes h$$

Edit : It is given that $f$ is an odd function.

Definitions :

$$f\star g = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(\tau-x)dx$$ and $$f\otimes g = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty  f(x)g(x+\tau)dx$$

Comment: wouldn't that be called a negative associative property?

Comment: Yes.  Certainly not distributive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\bar{h}(x)=h(-x)\tag{1}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
g\otimes h(x)
&=\int g(t)h(t+x)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int g(-t)h(-t+x)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int\bar{g}(t)h(x-t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\bar{g}\star h(x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore
$$
\begin{align}
g\otimes h(x)
&=\int g(t)h(t+x)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int g(t-x)h(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=h\otimes g(-x)\\
&=\overline{h\otimes g}(x)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{f\star g}(x)
&=f\star g(-x)\\
&=\int f(t)g(-x-t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int\bar{f}(-t)\bar{g}(x+t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int\bar{f}(t)\bar{g}(x-t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\bar{f}\star\bar{g}(x)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
(f\star g)\otimes h
&=\overline{f\star g}\star h\\
&=\bar{f}\star\bar{g}\star h\\
&=\bar{f}\star(g\otimes h)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Since $f$ is an odd function, $(5)$ becomes
$$
(f\star g)\otimes h=-f\star(g\otimes h)\tag{6}
$$

Comment: I forgot to mention that $f$ is an odd function. I guess it holds now. Actually $f(t )=1/t$, a kernel of Hilbert transform, I was expecting this result to prove my answer on the metric question. Please correct me if I am wrong.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RajeshD: It would be nice to add that $f$ is odd to the question.