# Is it possible to isometrically embed a bounded metric space into a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces

My practical intention is described in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/154905/14414), I am already doing this in my experiments with some success but I want a mathematical formulation in place not only to justify but also to verify that I am not missing anything crucial. A plain new question has arised out of it,

Can we have an isometric embedding of a bounded metric space into a complete normed vector space with the norm being $L^2$ norm. In case we can't, are there any conditions under which it is possible?

I've learnt an isometric embedding but with norm being a supremum norm in the answer by Piero to that question, but I need an $L^2$ norm to justify my experiments .

**EDIT**

The metric space in question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/521417/2987), A projective Hilbert space with translations identified and the metric is the arccosine metric defined there.  Is the square of this metric a conditionally positive definite kernel? As pointed by Alain Valette, as per the Schoeberg theorem we need $d^2(x,y)$ to be conditionally negative definite, for the isometric embedding into Hilbert space possible.

Comment: By "complete normed vector space with norm being $L^2$ norm", don't you simply mean a Hilbert space?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Yes, I wasn't sure about the definition. I'll google for it

Comment: No: the metric space on 4 elements underlying the tree with 4 vertices and 1 leaf (Mercedes-shape) is not isometrically embeddable into any Hilbert space. The question of efficiency of embeddings into Hilbert space is an important and active one, including old results of Bourgain and with connections to computer science.

Comment: To complement Yves'comments:
1) There is a well-known characterization of metrics $d$ such that $d(x,y)=\|f(x)-f(y)\|^2$ (note the square!) for some embedding of your space into Hilbert space: this happens iff $d$ is conditionally of negative type. This goes back to Schoenberg, I think.
2) I suggest you google "isometric embeddings" + "hilbert spaces" and look for connections with machine learning and SVM's - see in particular: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine

Comment: @YvesCornulier: I'm having trouble visualizing this metric space; could you be more explicit?

Comment: This is the usual combinatorial metric as defined on any connected graph. Here these are four vertices $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ with $d(x_0,x_i)=1$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $d(x_i,x_j)=2$ for $1\le i<j\le 3$.

Comment: Since subsets of a Hilbert space satisfy the parallelogram law:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law
you should restrict your question to only those metric spaces which satisfy this law.

Comment: @hot_queen: We need both an abelian group operation and compatible norm to formulate the parallelogram law as usually stated (for example, in that Wikipedia article). Is there a way to formulate it in the language of metric spaces?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/644502/2987